# Pseudomanifolds

Tags: general-topology, simplicial-stuff

An $n$-dimensional (closed) pseudomanifold is a finite simplicial complex $X$ such that

(i) every simplex is a face of an $n$-simplex

(ii) every $(n-1)$-simplex is a face of exactly two $n$-simplices

(iii) Given any two $n$-simplices $\sigma, \tau \in X$ there is a sequence of $n$-simplices $\sigma_0 = \sigma, \ldots, \sigma_k = \tau$ such that $\sigma_i \cap \sigma_{i+1}$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex for each $0 \leq i \leq k-1$.

These conditions imply that the polyhedron of a pseudomanifold is path-connected. Is it true that if a finite simplicial complex $X$ satisfies (i) and (ii) and has a path-connected polyhedron then it satisfies (iii)?

Comment: Just as an idea for a proof that its true, suppose you take a path connecting vertices for two simplices $\sigma$ and $\tau$. This path is homotopic to a path which transverses only simplex edges and vertices. I believe that if you can prove that the star of any vertex (the simplices that intersect that vertex) is a Pseudomanifold then you can prove that there exists a chain between $\sigma$ and $\tau$ as you describe.

Comment: "Simplicial stuff"?

Comment: @Neal Yeah, that tag rubs me the wrong way every time I see it. This is not OP's decision, the tag [has been used for a while](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simplicial-stuff). It was [criticized in the past](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2463/53153). I personally feel that the simple `(simplicial-)` would be better.

Answer (score 4):

Counterexample with $n=2$: let $X$ be the union of two hollow tetrahedra joined at a vertex. Here (i) and (ii) hold; (iii) fails, yet $X$ is path-connected.